# C++ : Symbols '<' and '>' in "template <smt> class_name" are overloaded or it's simply syntax?

Tags: c++

In "template  class_name" symbols '<' and '>' are overloaded or they are only specific syntax?

Comment: If those were overloads we could have meta-meta-programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are elements of the syntax.

From the n3337 draft standard:

**14 Templates**

> 1 A template defines a family of classes or functions or an alias for a family of types.
>
> *template-declaration:*
>
> > *template < template-parameter-list > declaration*
>
> *template-parameter-list:*
>
> > *template-parameter*
> >
> > *template-parameter-list , template-parameter*

Answer (score 1):

Its simply a syntax

*`template < parameter-list > declaration`*